# PHP. Problema con la iteración de un Array, obtener los elementos y guardarlos por separado

Tags: php, angular

Tengo este fragmento de código que recoge un array que llega desde Angular por POST así:

```
 $form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 

 foreach ($form_data as $value) {
    $name = $value;
    $ClaseTareas = new ClasePeriodicidad($name);
    $ClaseTareas->creaRegistro();
 }
```

Angular me indica por console.log que el Array sale así:

```
{"checkArrayt":["1","2","3","4","5","6","12","11","10"]}
```

La clase ClaseTareas se encarga de almacenarlo en la bbdd, sien embargo solamente me crea un registro con el contenido Array.
Si le indico el elemento del array específico así, sí me almacena el valor como "2":

```
 foreach ($form_data as $value) {
    $name = $value[1];
    $ClaseTareas = new ClasePeriodicidad($name);
    $ClaseTareas->creaRegistro();
 }
```

Necesito que me cree un registro por cada elemento del array con ese elemento como valor en "name". Ayuda, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)['checkArrayt']; 

 foreach ($form_data as $value) {
    $name = $value;
    $ClaseTareas = new ClasePeriodicidad($name);
    $ClaseTareas->creaRegistro();
 }
```

La opción true en la función json_decode hace que el objeto obtenido del json sea un array asociativo. Después de json_decode accedo al array, al campo checkArrayt y después recorremos los elementos en el foreach, espero que te lo solucione.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas reconvertir el JSON a array para leer cada dato. Puedes hacer simplemente esto:

```
foreach ($form_data->checkArrayt as $k=>$name) {
    $ClaseTareas = new ClasePeriodicidad($name);
    $ClaseTareas->creaRegistro();
 }
```

Explico:

- Con `$form_data->checkArrayt` vas a acceder al array de elementos que hay en la clave `checkArrayt` del JSON.
- Con el `as $k=>$name` estarás accediendo a cada clave `$k` y valor `$name` de los elementos (He usado la notación `as $k=>$v` porque [según benchmarks que se han hecho](https://phpbench.com) la lectura de los arrays es más rápida de ese modo).

Con eso no necesitas nada más.

He aquí una prueba:

```
$form_data = json_decode('{"checkArrayt":["1","2","3","4","5","6","12","11","10"]}'); 
foreach ($form_data->checkArrayt as $k=>$name) {
     echo $name.PHP_EOL;
    //$ClaseTareas = new ClasePeriodicidad($name);
    //$ClaseTareas->creaRegistro();
}
```

**Salida:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
12
11
10
```